# Is the navigation prop immutable / pure? - react navigation v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation v4, and I need to know if the `navigation` prop is immutable because I want to wrap my component with `React.memo`

For context here is my (hopefully) pure React component:

```
    // notice the React.memo and the usage of navigation.state.routes and navigation.navigate
    const TabBarComponent: React.FC<Props> = React.memo(({ navigation }) => {
      const onSelect = (index) => {
        const { [index]: selectedTabRoute } = navigation.state.routes
        navigation.navigate(selectedTabRoute.routeName)
      }
    ...
   }
```

Comment: For future readers the question was answered here: https://twitter.com/icookandcode/status/1312134830625153026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question based on this [tweet](https://twitter.com/icookandcode/status/1312134830625153026) by Satyajit Sahoo.

> It's not immutable, but it only changes when it needs to (e.g.
> navigation.state changes). In v5, navigation.state is moved to a
> separate route prop (or in case of tab bar, state prop). So, yeah you
> can wrap components accepting it in React.memo.
>
> However, the tab bar also accepts more props such as a descriptors
> object containing options for each screen. So it depends whether it'll
> have much difference depending on when those other props change.
>
> All screens are wrapped in React.memo by default.
>
> Essentially, React Navigation doesn't change props when it doesn't
> need to.
>
> And it doesn't make anything immutable (e.g. with Object.freeze), but
> they aren't treated as mutable internally and you are not supposed to
> mutate them, similar to other things in React ecosystem.